# How much memory does a closure take?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, closures

I'm wondering what is the memory footprint of a JavaScript closure?
What does this amount depend on?

The first obvious factor for memory consumption by a closure is the number of variables it captures and theirs sizes.
Ok, let's assume that we have a simple closure:

```
var counter = (function () {
    var num = 0;

    return function () {
        return ++num;
     }
}());
```

How much memory it will take?
If it tough to say the exact numbers, I'd like to know at least the magnitude of those. Is it 10, 100 bytes or even more?
Does it significantly different between JavaScript implementations?

I hope answers to those questions, especially with some numbers, will help me and other readers clarify:
Is it a good practice to use closures as much as you need?
Or you should use it with care and avoid it when possible because the overhead from using a closure can probably outweigh benefits it gives.

In other words, I hope I'll be able to better understand which situations are worth using a closure and which aren't.

**EDIT 1**:
To address the @MaximillianLaumeister's comment that the questions is too broad, let's rephrase it a bit:
**Which parts in memory such a closure consist of? How big they are relative to each other and maybe in absolute numbers? Are they the same across JavaScript engines?**
From the comments below, the parts should be:

1. an object with the same number of properties as captured variables (@Dan)
2. the by far largest part of the closure is its (compiled) code (@Bergi)

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow in my opinion, but to give you some super vague answers, they take up "not too much" memory, they will probably vary between implementations but not grossly, and I wouldn't worry about the overhead at all unless you're creating closures inside of a loop.

Comment: the size of a scope is about the same as an object with the same number of properties. A closure is another object with a fixed number of properties.  See https://es5.github.io/#x10.2 and https://es5.github.io/#x13.2

Comment: "*The first obvious factor for memory consumption by a closure*" - the by far largest part of the closure is its (compiled) code. Luckily, *that* is shared through all instances created from the same function expression.

Comment: "which situations are worth using a closure and which aren't" Against what alternative? Creating separate functions for each potential useage? In that case create closure **always**!

Comment: @Bergi, What compiled code does a closure contain? I thought a closure is represented internally as kind of a data object with captured variables as its properties. Why it needs a compiled code and, even more surprising to me, why this part is the largest part of a closure?

Comment: @Volodya, the alternatives for using a closure depend on a particular situation. For instance, if you want to use a closure just to keep a variable value between function calls like in my example, you may keep it as a property of the function object.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov: A closure is a *function*. This function object internally references its code and the environment that it closed over (the captured variables). The environment is really really small, the code is quite a bunch of data. So what size do you want to know? Basically all functions are closures in JS and have all of these references, but the size of the environment they reference is different.

Comment: @Bergi: Good point that closure is a function, therefore it needs to be compiled into code! Can't believe I've missed that before :) Returning to my example closure function, it consists of 2 simple statements: 1. creation of a variable of a primitive type and initialization it with a constant and 2. returning a reference to an inner function object. Let's suppose we don't count the size of compiled code of the inner function object because, using a closure approach or not, it's essential part of a program logic.

Comment: @Bergi: (Continued) So at first glance, the compiled code of the closure function should be very small, I'd say about 20 - 30 bytes on x86, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Bergi: Regarding your statements about the size of the environment. There are a fixed amount of memory each single environment requires to maintain its internal data structures and a varying amount of memory to hold the captured variables, right? If so, how big is this fixed size part?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov: No, the code size is quite larger, as JS is not (or only as an optimisation) compiled, but interpreter. Much metadata (both about the code itself and the execution). But as you say, it doesn't matter, it's an essential part of the program and would exist even in other approaches. The fixed part of the environment is pretty small, about 10 bytes iirc, not larger than the fixed part of an object would be. But really, if you have to know exactly, use the memory profiler/snapshot tools of your debugger (in Chrome devtools).

Comment: @Bergi: Thank you! As the question is reopened, you might compose your postings as an answer. This is the most comprehensive set of info regarding my question so far.